# Restore Windows 7 to Defaults

Tags: windows-7, restore, factory-defaults

A while back I installed Win7 on my compute - it had XP before. I now want to restore it back to the default Win7 - like just after the installation. I would do a fresh install from an ISO, but when I tried to use my key on another computer it wouldn't work, so I'm not going to do a fresh install in case that happens.

So how can I restore it? As I installed the OS, not the manufacturer, it does not have a recovery partition/program.

Answer (score 0):

Go the Restore point there you may find some restore points created by some software's that is when you install some application it will create a restore point so select that one and restore it.

Go to

> ->start menu
>   ->accessories
>   ->system tools
>   ->restore point

Comment: No - tried that already - the last restore point is about one month ago... and I installed Win7 about 6 months ago...